# Auto Complete is Very slow data show in input field How fast

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Jquery Virsion is 1.12.4 ui verison is 1.12.1 
I think its virsion problem .How to solve this problem 
When I use another virtion autocomplete properly work.
Jquery Virsion is 1.12.4 ui verison is 1.12.1 
I think its virsion problem .How to solve this problem 
When I use another virtion autocomplete properly work.
View part

```
<div class="input-group" >
                        <input type="text" name="search" id="txtinput" autocomplete="off" style="border:0px; background-color:#1e91de; color:white;placeholder-color:red;"  placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Ajax Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtinput').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= base_url() ?>Autocomplete/SearchResult",
                    data: { term: request.term},
                    minLength: 1,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                      var resp =   $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.value,
                                label: item.label
                            };
                        });
                        response(resp.slice(0, 4));
                    }
                })
            },
            focus: function() {
             return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#txtinput').val(ui.item.value);
                 return true;
            }
        }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item){
      return $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-row'></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(item.label)
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
    });
```

controller

```
public function SearchResult()
{
    $term = $this->input->get('term');
    $getDetail = $this->Autocomplete_model->getSearch($term);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($getDetail as $row) {

   $temp_array = array();
   $temp_array['value'] = $row['title'];
   $temp_array['label'] = '<img src="<php site_url() ?>uploads/product/'.$row['picture'].'" width="100" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row['title'].'';
   $data[] = $temp_array;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model

```
  function getSearch($name)
{
    $select = $this->db->query("SELECT products.title,product_picture.picture FROM products
            LEFT JOIN product_picture
        ON products.id=product_picture.pid
        WHERE title LIKE '%".$name."%' LIMIT 5 ");

    return $select->result_array();
}
```

Comment: If you know the old version is the problem then why not you use the new version? Are you not able to use newer version?

Comment: when I use new version  getting an error  because  existing project already use the old version